# How do you parse HTML file on Solaris 10 UNIX box to put all values within <td> elements into CSV file?

Tags: php, perl, bash, parsing, solaris

I'm pretty familiar with PHP including command line, semi-familiar with BASH scripting, and no experience with Perl or other languages but willing to use whatever works.

The HTML file I am trying to parse is 700,000+ lines, 61MB. I cannot change the source that builds the HTML table, only download the entire table via **wget http://10.1.1.2/file.pl**.

Here's an example format of the HTML code that I'm trying to parse:

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Objects</TITLE>
    <STYLE type="text/css">
    a:hover
    {
    color:red
    }
    </STYLE>
    </HEAD>
  <BODY>
  <IMG src="http://10.1.1.2/images/logo.gif"/>
  <BR/><BR/>
  <TABLE border="0">
    <TR>
      <TH>Objects</TH>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD><HR style="width:227px"></TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <table border=1 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0><tr><th><b>Subtype</b></th><th><b>Object</b>    </th></tr>
    <tr><td>10GigEthernet</td><td>SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/10/0/0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>10GigEthernet</td><td>SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/13/0/0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>10GigEthernet</td><td>SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/13/3/0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>10GigEthernet</td><td>SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/3/0/0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>10GigEthernet</td><td>SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/3/0/0-5</td></tr>
    ... 700,000 more lines ...
  </table>        </BODY>
</HTML>
```

What I'd like in the CSV:

```
Subtype,Object
10GigEthernet,SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/10/0/0
10GigEthernet,SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/13/0/0
10GigEthernet,SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/13/3/0
10GigEthernet,SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/3/0/0
10GigEthernet,SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/3/0/0-5
```

I'd appreciate any help you can give! Thanks in advance.

Result from @shellter's code:

```
# wget http://10.1.1.2/reports/file.pl
--2012-01-19 06:56:59--  http://10.1.1.2/reports/file.pl
Connecting to 10.1.1.2... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified
Saving to: `file.pl'

    [          <=>                          ] 61,000,000  1.01M/s   in 58s     

2012-01-19 06:58:00 (1.01 MB/s) - `file.pl' saved [61000000]

# sed -n '/<\/td>/{
>            s@<tr><td>@@;
>            s@</td>@XaYbZc@;
>            s@<td>@@;
>            s@</td></tr>@@;
>            s/XaYbZc/,/
>            s/^    //
>            p
>           }' file.pl > routerList.csv
# ls -l
total 203408
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root     61000000 Jan 19 06:58 file.pl
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root     42708247 Jan 19 06:58 routerList.csv
# head routerList.csv
10GigEthernetn,SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/10/0/0
10GigEthernetn,SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/13/0/0
10GigEthernetn,SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/13/3/0
10GigEthernetn,SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/3/0/0
10GigEthernetn,SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/3/0/0-5
```

Comment: You would just use the [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) parser and get the data you want by looping it or with [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php). have a go at writing it yourself and come back if you have any problems ;-)

Comment: I've wrote a script that kind of works using PHP command line but it's been running for ~8 hours now and it's only on line 50,000. I use the DOM method in the PHP script and then used a for loop to pull the <td> values. Since this is taking so long, I figured there had to be a more efficient way.

Comment: Show your code so it may be improved at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Try using XPath to obtain the elements you want before you loop the document - although with a ~61MB file, whatever you do is going to take a while (8 hours is a lot though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I have to agree with most of the comments like 'use a DOM, or XPATH, etc.', 
you are lucky in this case that all data you want to process is on one line. If there are ever linebreaks anywhere in that data, then this will not work AND it will be essentially impossible to get a working solution is sed. So forwarned of these issues, try this

```
 wget http://10.1.1.2/file.pl

 sed -n '/<\/td>/{
           s@<tr><td>@@;
           s@</td>@XaYbZc@;
           s@<td>@@;
           s@</td></tr>@@;
           s/XaYbZc/,/
           s/^    //
           p
          }' file.pl > routerList.csv

cat routerList.csv
10GigEthernet,SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/10/0/0
10GigEthernet,SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/13/0/0
10GigEthernet,SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/13/3/0
10GigEthernet,SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/3/0/0
10GigEthernet,SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/3/0/0-5
```

The sed script is using the '@' char as the match/replace section delimiter.

First we take the first `<tr><td>` on the line and delete it,

We then take the first `</td>` and replace it with XaYbZc as a temp marker.

Remove the remaining opening `<td>`.

Remove the trailing `</td></tr>`

Replace the temporary XaYbZc with the ','

Remove 4 spaces at the front of the line.

Print the buffer. (Done!)

I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think set will be able to reach the data as it's saved in the "file.pl" file. Once you have the file try this: cat file.pl| sed ....

Comment: Thanks, yes, See my edits. but avoid the UUOC award ;-> . Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

I would abandon using the Right Way (using a real parser) and just process it with a regex.

This (in Perl) is fragile and error prone, but ought to be about as fast as you can get...

```
print "$1,$2\n" while $html =~ /<tr><td>([^<]+)<\/td><td>([^<]+)/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty with Perl and its `XML::LibXML` module
(which doesn't come standard with Perl, but will usually be easy to install,
once you know how to install CPAN modules):

```
/tmp % xpath -He '//td//text()' test.html | perl -pe '$x=1-$x and s#$/#,#'
10GigEthernet,SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/10/0/0
10GigEthernet,SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/13/0/0
10GigEthernet,SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/13/3/0
10GigEthernet,SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/3/0/0
10GigEthernet,SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/3/0/0-5
```

Here, [xpath](http://www.win.tue.nl/%7Erp/bin/xpath-rp) is a simple Perl script I wrote to select stuff from XML/HTML documents using XPath.
The second Perl command is a quick and dirty way to reformat the results into two-column format,
that will fail if your document has other kinds of `<td/>`s that you don't want to be in the output.

So this probably won't do exactly what you need right now, but especially if you anticipate having to do more of these kinds of selections in the future, you probably want to write a script you can adjust later, and in that case, this is a possible starting point.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
 sed '1i\Subtype,Object'$'\n''/^\s*<tr><td>/!d;s/\s*<tr>\|<\/tr>\s*//g;s/<td>\([^<]*\)<\/td>/\1,/g;s/.$//' file
Subtype,Object
10GigEthernet,SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/10/0/0
10GigEthernet,SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/13/0/0
10GigEthernet,SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/13/3/0
10GigEthernet,SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/3/0/0
10GigEthernet,SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/3/0/0-5
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers so far say "you should do it the Right Way" then show how to do it the "Wrong Way". Here is an example of the Right Way. This version uses a DOM parser (specifically [`Mojo::DOM`](http://p3rl.org/Mojo%3a%3aDOM) though others will work similarly) and [`Text::CSV`](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aCSV).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# Use this for real
#use Mojo::UserAgent;
#my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
#my $dom = $ua->get('http://10.1.1.2/file.pl')->res->dom;

# Use this for test
use Mojo::DOM;
my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new(do { local $/; <DATA> });

# Common code (test and real)

use Text::CSV;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new;
my $output;

sub append_row {
  return unless @_;
  $csv->combine(@_) or die $csv->status();
  $output .= $csv->string() . "\n"; 
}

my $table = $dom->find('table')->[1];
append_row( $table->find('th')->pluck('all_text')->each );

$table->find('tr')->each(sub{
  append_row( $_->find('td')->pluck('text')->each );
});

print $output;


__DATA__
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Objects</TITLE>
    <STYLE type="text/css">
    a:hover
    {
    color:red
    }
    </STYLE>
    </HEAD>
  <BODY>
  <IMG src="http://10.1.1.2/images/logo.gif"/>
  <BR/><BR/>
  <TABLE border="0">
    <TR>
      <TH>Objects</TH>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD><HR style="width:227px"></TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <table border=1 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0><tr><th><b>Subtype</b></th><th><b>Object</b>    </th></tr>
    <tr><td>10GigEthernet</td><td>SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/10/0/0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>10GigEthernet</td><td>SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/13/0/0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>10GigEthernet</td><td>SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/13/3/0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>10GigEthernet</td><td>SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/3/0/0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>10GigEthernet</td><td>SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/3/0/0-5</td></tr>
    ... 700,000 more lines ...
  </table>        </BODY>
</HTML>
```

This results in

```
Subtype,Object
10GigEthernet,SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/10/0/0
10GigEthernet,SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/13/0/0
10GigEthernet,SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/13/3/0
10GigEthernet,SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/3/0/0
10GigEthernet,SNFCCAMK34T-TenGigE0/3/0/0-5
```

much like the others, but handles all kinds of edge cases. In my opinion, with modern DOM (or even XPath) parsers, doing it the right way is easier than crafting a regex anyway, plus you avoid all of the pitfalls that come from doing it the wrong way; so why not just do it the right way first?